# Is there a way to convert an IO handle to a socket?

Tags: haskell, networking

I'm messing around with Networking in Haskell, and need to modify how long connectTo will attempt to connect before timing out. Unfortunately, connectTo returns a handle, which doesn't have any modifiable timeout parameters. Does anyone know of any ways to get a Socket from a handle returned by connectTo? (Or knows of any ways of modifying the timeout using only a handle)

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `System.Timeout.timeout`?  That might be sufficient for your needs.  [I don't believe there's a way](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Handle+-%3E+IO+Socket) to convert a general `Handle` to a `Socket`, since those are quite different entities from an OS perspective.

Comment: I actually realized after asking that my question isn't answerable in it's current form, because I want to change the behavior of connectTo (reduce the time before it times out), not change the resulting handle. I'd delete the question, but I don't want the rep change. And doesn't the module you mention add a timeout? I want to reduce the current timeout from ~10 seconds to 1 (or even less).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket operates at a lower level than Handle. By looking at the source of the `network` package, I was able to come up with the following way of modifying the timeout using handle:

```
import qualified Control.Exception as Exception
import           Data.Int (Int64)
import           Network
import           Network.BSD
import qualified Network.Socket as Socket (accept)
import           Network.Socket hiding (accept, socketPort, recvFrom, sendTo, PortNumber, sClose)
import           Network.Socket.Options (setSendTimeout)
import           System.IO

type MicroSeconds = Int64

myconnectTo :: HostName           -- Hostname
          -> PortID             -- Port Identifier
          -> MicroSeconds
          -> IO Handle          -- Connected Socket

myconnectTo hostname (Service serv) t = do
    proto <- getProtocolNumber "tcp"
    bracketOnError
        (socket AF_INET Stream proto >>= \x
         -> setSendTimeout x t >> return x)
        (sClose)  -- only done if there's an error
        (\sock -> do
          port  <- getServicePortNumber serv
          he    <- getHostByName hostname
          connect sock (SockAddrInet port (hostAddress he))
          socketToHandle sock ReadWriteMode
        )

myconnectTo hostname (PortNumber port) t = do
    proto <- getProtocolNumber "tcp"
    bracketOnError
        (socket AF_INET Stream proto >>= \x
         -> setSendTimeout x t >> return x)
        (sClose)  -- only done if there's an error
        (\sock -> do
          he <- getHostByName hostname
          connect sock (SockAddrInet port (hostAddress he))
          socketToHandle sock ReadWriteMode
        )

bracketOnError = Exception.bracketOnError
```

Note that I haven't actually tested the code, but it typechecks. It should be noted that it will only work for IPv4 systems but it is easily adaptable to IPv6 from the [network](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network) package. I'm using the [setSendTimeout](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-socket-options-0.2.0.1/docs/Network-Socket-Options.html#v:setSendTimeout) function from `network-options` package to manipulate the timeout.